efficient use of vlookup in an if statement
I have this cell formula...
=IF(  (VLOOKUP(E2,$L$1:$M$12,2,0)+D2)<>"",  (VLOOKUP(E2,$L$1:$M$12,2,0)+D2),"")

It seems like a prime situation where someone would have coded something like
=IF(  (VLOOKUP(E2,$L$1:$M$12,2,0)+D2)<>"",cond,"")

where cond was the evaluation of the previous test criteria.
Does such a thing exist?

I can't speak to the efficiency of any particular solution, but I suspect intermediate results are cached internally and this can be accomplished with more cells if not - try it and see!

If you mean make another column with the test result in it, then use that appropriate cell reference from that column in the original formula then that is even less  efficient, despite it making the original formula look nicer.
It does indeed seem likely the test result is cached and it's that which I imagine someone would realize would be useful to 'code-tap' into.

Now that you found an answer, please write an actual one. Or decide that your issue is not worth to help others and delete it. Just don't leave your question unanswered, please, this is not a forum.

b7's reply (I presume is you) isn't an answer to my question.
Maybe if you re-read my question you'll realize I'm not looking for a solution - which my code actually contains(!!), but is there a way of doing what I'm doing in the way I posit may be possible. Please write comments that are not unnecessarily' prickly'

Well, ti7 suspects the existence of a cache, and your following comment backs this. I presume you did your homework and scanned the documentation to find that there is no such thing as a function cond(). Which would be useless, as the value is cached, as you confirmed. So the literal answer is "no," and the reason is "it is not necessary." It's all in your comment, which therefore answers your question.

I'm using 'cond' as a placeholder/example, representing some possible function / way / hack / trick to which what I propose could be done. It's the kind of useful thing I've seen programmers devise and would be incredibly useful at simplifying and reducing buggy formulas, hence the reason I'm asking.
I haven't confirmed anything other than a shared guess at b7's assumption about  some kind of cache.
I appreciate your time but I must say it has done nothing to the furtherance of my question.

There is a similar question for Excel related to this. But since the method in LO is different, I'll post the answer here.

Click on the first cell where you want to use the formula. This is important because the un-anchored (not marked with $) cell reference of the formula will change in reference to this cell location.
Sheet --> Named Ranges and Expressions --> Define
In the "Name" field, type in the name of your variable. Lets call it MyVar for this example.
In the "Range or formula expression" field, type in your formula. In your example, it would be VLOOKUP(E2,$L$1:$M$12,2,0)+D2
Click "Add"
In the formula area, use the Name to reference the variable. In this example, it would be: If(MyVar <> "",MyVar, "")


Because Excel is a proprietary software, we can largely just speculate and experiment to identify the behavior of its internal logic - however, I strongly suspect intermediate results are both cached and reorganized by whatever interpreter/compiler Excel uses internally, so multiple instances of the same function with the same arguments are not meaningfully expensive to re-request both within an individual cell and further within all cells in the same sheet

The caching of intermediate results is known as memoizing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), and is a common practice defined by creating a hashmap of functions and arguments when a result is very expensive to compute or may be requested multiple times
frequently this sort of cache has extra accounting such that the cache doesn't grow indefinitely
the Python docs have a great example of this https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache

While the interpreter/compiler itself may discover and simplify intermediate result requests in its representation of the cell calculation, sometimes called hoisting (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)



Downvoted because the question was not about Excel. Maybe you can edit to fix this problem and I'll undo the vote.

@JimK sheesh .. I've used libreoffice for years and never actually seen a proper Question about it here .. let me go find out

Maybe I should have explicitly stated the context was Libreoffice Calc and not just via the tags. Sorry.
Sometimes my test criteria are quite long and involved, and I occasionally have typo's in the condition. Obviously one can copy and paste the test criteria into the 'do this / action' section, but typo's get copied too, and even with no typos', if improvements are made to the test criteria more work to copy and paste it again. A 'cond' way as my questions points towards, would avoid any and all fiddling. Likely some coder has done it.
